# Splice from ng-options in select drop downusing filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, filter

How can I splice some elements in an array to display it in ng options

Heres the JSON

```
    $scope.result=[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "min",

            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "hour",

            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "second",

            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "inch",

            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "km",

            }
    ]
```

I want to splice inch and km from the array and display it it select dropdown

```
<select ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in result"><option value="">--Select---</option></select>
```

Have also tries inline filter that will only display based on id's like tihis    `<select ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in result|filter:{id:'!4'}"><option value="">--Select---</option>
</select>`

But this will splice only one element ie.,with id:5(km).I want to splice id:4 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native javascript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for your work

```
var newResult = $scope.result.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.name === 'km' || obj.name === 'inch';
});
console.log(newResult); // will give expected result.
```

You can assign the result of filter to the key in `scope` on which you want to loop.